# Print different values with random in python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

```
from random import randint

result = []
colors = {1: "Red", 2: "Green", 3: "Blue", 4: "White"}

while True:
    for key in colors:
        ball = randint(1,4)
        probability = (ball/10)
        result.append(probability)

    break

print(result)
```

This code gives me 4 values which is ok, but I'd like to have no repetitions. So if program took e.g "White", it won't include it to iteration. Any ideas?

Comment: Look into `random.shuffle`

Comment: the `while` loop is pointless; and i'm not clear what you're trying to do, you iterate over `colors` but never use `key`

Comment: If you have a bigger list, and you need to draw `n` elements from it without replacement, you can just shuffle the list, and take `draw = big_list[:n]`.

Comment: @L3viathan better to `sample` for that case

Comment: @Chris_Rands when I have `sample` I got `TypeError: sample() missing 1 required positional argument: 'k'`

Comment: @Hiddenguy well you need to specify the sample size, read the docs when you try a new function https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample

Comment: @Chris_Rands if the list is _very big_, yes. If it's just "bigger than n", e.g. 10 colours, out of which 4 are chosen: Eh ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have 4 values and you just want a random permutation of them, just use `random.shuffle`:

```
from random import shuffle

colors = {1: "Red", 2: "Green", 3: "Blue", 4: "White"}

balls = list(colors)
shuffle(balls)
result = [ball/10 for ball in balls]

print(result)
```

Another option (especially good with larger lists, because shuffling a list is "slow") is the use of `random.sample`:

```
from random import sample

colors = {1: "Red", 2: "Green", 3: "Blue", 4: "White"}

result = [ball/10 for ball in sample(colors, 4)]

print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether that particular value has been taken or not.

```
list_taken = []
number = randint(1,n)
while number in list_taken:
    number = randint(1,n)
list_taken.append(number)
```

So what above 4 lines of code do is, maintain a list of already taken values and repeat finding new values until it gets a new one.

Hope this helps!